# What is log4j's default DEBUG log file dumping path

Tags: java, logging, log4j, executable-jar

I have a jar file without the source code and that has to be executed multiple times in order to get a result.

The jar file has the log4j in it and it is set to the INFO level.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R
# Appender Configuration
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

There are some bugs in the jar and i want to check the DEBUG level logs.

I have checked the following post:

[What is log4j's default log file dumping path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335984/what-is-log4js-default-log-file-dumping-path)

[Path of log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545861/path-of-log-file)

[Log file is empty (log4j)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288393/log-file-is-empty-log4j)

but did not find any helpful information

So is there any default location where they are placed and i can check them out .???

Comment: log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender -> seems it only logs to console. If there were a file appender it must be stated somewhere (FileAppender or RollingFileAppender)

Comment: No there is only ConsoleAppender. And i want logs through `log.debug("Hello")` if no DEBUG level defined in log4j.rootLogger . Is there is any default location if no DEBUG level defined and log.debug("") is used somewhere in the code?